# How to set priority to get the lock from mutex?

Tags: linux

I have two threads, all are running on same core. I want that when 2nd thread and 1st thread will ask for the lock then 2nd thread will only get the lock immediately from mutex and 1st thread should wait. I want to that this priority should be given to 2nd thread.

Answer (score 1):

Since both threads are running on the same core, they are timesliced. This means that at any given moment in time either thread `A` or thread `B` is executing (or neither). To have the lock biased in the manner you describe, thread `A` would need to be able to anticipate thread `B`'s actions, and hold off from acquiring the lock if thread `B` is about to need it. This is a major can of worms.

My recommendation is to rethink your design.

Comment: My question is when two threads will ask for lock simultaneously then lock should be given to thread which has highest priority.

Comment: @JasdeepSinghArora: My point is that the two threads **can't** ask for the lock simultaneously. This is simply not possible in the circumstances you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a guarantee that any particular thread will "win" in a SMP system, so unless you are on a single-core system, you can't do that (and it may or may not work in the single-core case, depending on how the scheduler works).

Consider:
    while(something)
    {
        mutex_lock();
        ... do stuff... 
        mutex_unlock();
    }

Now, if we have two threads running this code, you will end up with a race of who gets to "mutex_lock" first. Most likely, the thread that held the lock will win, since the other thread has to be scheduled by the sheduler first, where the one running the loop only has a jump to the first instruction in the loop.

So, if you require two threads to work in sync, you need to use some sort of step-wise synchronisation mechanism, where one thread waits for the other to "get going" before it continues. There are several ways you could do that, but all will require both threads using a shared IPC mechanism.

If you explain more about what your threads are doing, there may be a simple method to solve the problem, or it may be complicated...